# How to create a new column timestamp from the existing ISO column in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection with `createdAt` column in ISO date time format.
I want add another column `timestamp` unix time of `createdAt` column.
I can see there are options like `addFields` and `project` but these operations are returning values instead of commiting the changes.

Is there a to do it in 1 query for all the documents in the collection?
Using Mongodb v4

Mongo play link https://mongoplayground.net/p/PJrodGYQsko

```
Data
[
  {
    "_id": "1597666154",
    "unixtime": ISODate("2013-10-01T00:00:00.000Z")
  }
]

Expected:
  {
    "_id": "1597666154",
    "createdAt": ISODate("2013-10-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "unixtime": NumberLong(1380585600000)
  }
```

Comment: can you show what have you tried?

Comment: @turivishal added the example I tried

Comment: just use `$addFields` instead of `$project` stage.

Comment: Then how to update it in db

Comment: okay, use [update with aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/) starting from MongoDB 4.2, see working [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/lg-gn1tSjM8)

Comment: @turivishal Thanks. Sorry I forgot to mention the version I am using. It is v4. And in that this aggregation doesn't work

Comment: ok so you have to do 2 queries, find query and update query.

Comment: That I got it. But unable to utilize the query. Can you please add an example?

Comment: i think both are easy queries when you just see documentation of [findOne()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOne/) and [updateOne()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateOne/).